# What does $\mathrm{sgn}(\theta)$ mean in algebra/ group theory?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Today my lecture wrote

$$
A_n =\{ \theta \in S_n : \mathrm{sgn}(\theta) =1 \}
$$
I'm used to that $\mathrm{sgn}$ means the sign function either $-1$ or $1$. But what does it mean here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sign function for the symmetric group $S_n$ is defined as $1$ for an element that can be written as a product of an even number of transpostions and $-1$ for an element that can be written as a product of an odd number of transpositions.

Answer (score 2):

Here you are talking about the signature of a permutation (symmetric group), which can be either 1 or -1